# Looking for a non-scrolling, no-drop-down-box alternative to shiny's selectInput()

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny application that processes and displays any single table from a given set of tables. The user selects a table via the selectInput() function which, when clicked, displays all the available table titles in a scrolling drop-down box. The application is a bit complicated, but it works fine.

Now I would like to offer the user an alternative way to select a table, instead of the scrolling drop-down selectInput() box. I would like to list the tables on the screen, all of them one after the other, and have the application respond when one in this list is clicked. In effect, I would like to use a different kind of selectInput() control that does not use a scrolling drop-down box, but instead shows all the options on the screen at once.

I have not been able to find an existing shiny control that does this so I am seeking advice on how I might proceed.

Comment: The first thing I thought of reading your question are `radioButtons`. As an alternative you could render seperate `actionLink`'s / `actionButton`'s for each table or list the tables in another table and show the sub-table after a row is clicked... and so on.

Comment: Have you tried the option `selectize = FALSE` in `selectInput`?

Comment: As suggested, I tried selectize=FALSE, but that had no obvious effect.Using buttons sounds like a possibility and I will give it a try. Thanks.